# .bat file overriding answer

Tags: windows-7, windows, batch, batch-file

When I made this batch file, when typing y and n for the first time it works fine, but as soon as I choose n, every single time I try inputting something, it opens up the 7000 songs wpl list then closes it and replaces it with Rick Astley...

HELP!

```
@echo off
:Ask
echo Would you like to listen to the best songs out of the 7000 I have?(Y/N)
set INPUT=
set /P INPUT=Type input: %=%
If /I "%INPUT%"=="y" goto yes 
If /I "%INPUT%"=="n" goto lolno
echo Incorrect input & goto Ask
:yes
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Playlists/"The Best of the 7000 songs that I have.wpl"
:lolno
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Downloads/Music/"Various Artists"/"The Number One 80's Album Disc 2"/"06 Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3"
```

Comment: looks like the location of `"` caused it. have you tried `start "c:/Users/MyName/Music/Downloads/Music/Various Artists/The Number One 80's Album Disc 2/06 Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3"`?

Answer (score 0):

`start` uses the first quoted argument it encounters as the *window title* for a new `cmd` session. If you want to `start` anything that has spaces in it, you have to do it this way:

```
start "" "%UserProfile%\Music\Playlists\The Best of the 7000 songs that I have.wpl"
```

Also, use backslashes in `cmd` exclusively when dealing with paths as arguments to built-in commands. The Windows API is smart enough to translate slashes for you, but `cmd` uses `/` for switches and named arguments and its parser gets confused sometimes, so best avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The way labels work is it goes to that label and then continues downwards. With your example:

```
:yes
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Playlists/"The Best of the 7000 songs that I have.wpl"
:lolno
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Downloads/Music/"Various Artists"/"The Number One 80's Album Disc 2"/"06 Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3"
```

`goto yes` will run (jump to `:yes` and continue downwards):

```
:yes
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Playlists/"The Best of the 7000 songs that I have.wpl"
:lolno
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Downloads/Music/"Various Artists"/"The Number One 80's Album Disc 2"/"06 Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3"
```

`goto lolno` will run (jump to `:lolno` and continue downwards):

```
:lolno
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Downloads/Music/"Various Artists"/"The Number One 80's Album Disc 2"/"06 Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3"
```

What you need to do is add either a `goto :eof` (eof means "end of file") or `exit /b` at the end of any label segment you don't intend to fall through:

```
:yes
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Playlists/"The Best of the 7000 songs that I have.wpl"
goto :eof

:lolno
start c:/Users/MyName/Music/Downloads/Music/"Various Artists"/"The Number One 80's Album Disc 2"/"06 Never Gonna Give You Up.mp3"
goto :eof
```

Either command will end the script there. You could also define a different label under them to jump to, if you wanted.

Comment: Damn, I missed that one. That's what I get for answering questions in the morning ;)